# Android ParseObject.createWithoutData sometimes returns cached data?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

According to the Parse API, calling ParseObject.createWithoutData(objectName, objectId) will return a ParseObject with no data.

But it seems like some data is being cached. Take the following code for example:

```
ParseObject parseObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData("SomeObject", "objectId");
parseObject.add("someList", someValue); // Atomically add someValue to someList
parseObject.save();
```

Suppose I run this a bunch of times without a network connection. The save will fail, and I expect that each subsequent call of this code will give me a clean parseObject.

But... Sometimes after the first line executes, the returned ParseObject contains "someList" with the value that I previously added to it.

Does anybody know why it's doing this? It seems like it's caching data, but only sometimes. I don't want it to cache data. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the local datastore being enabled. I removed the following from my Application.onCreate method:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore();
```

And it doesn't seem to be caching data anymore.